# need specific data from a url with file_get_contents ()

Tags: php, html, get, file-get-contents

I am trying to read a URL with `file_get_contents()`. I need to get only `$invoice` from the page.

`$invoice` appears on sentence like the following example as a number 789621 :

```
<code><div class="show invoice invoice_number_rajhi"><a href="/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people" class="link-blue" onclick="$.fn.colorbox({title:&quot;People who visit this&quot;,onComplete:show.onPeopleOpening,onCleanup:show.onPeopleClosing,href:&‌​quot;/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people&quot;}); return false">789621 paid</a> show this</div></code>
```

and if it appears as the following example , how could i do it ?

```
  <code><li class="js-stat-show js-stat-show stat-still"> <a href="#" class="request-invoice-popup" data-activity-popup-title="invoice 789621 paid" > paid <strong>789621</strong> </a> </li></code>
```

Comment: so its not returning as json ?? instead its plain text ??

Comment: i tried this, <code>$urlm = file_get_contents(".$url.");
 $result = json_decode($urlm);$invoice = ???</code>
in $invoice "3rd step " i don't know what should i type

Comment: can u post the complete string that u got from $urlm = file_get_contents(".$url.");

Comment: show something include this
<div class="show invoice invoice_number_rajhi"><a href="/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people" class="link-blue" onclick="$.fn.colorbox({title:&quot;People who visit this&quot;,onComplete:show.onPeopleOpening,onCleanup:show.onPeopleClosing,href:&quot;/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people&quot;}); return false">789621 paid</a> show this</div>

Comment: i need only to get the number "789621" from that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions in PHP:

```
$myurl = "theUrlYouWant";

preg_match("/return false\"\>(.*?) paid/i", file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);

$invoice = $matches[1];

echo($invoice);
```

Now, the variable $invoice should be equal to the invoice number

Comment: Thanks and if it appears as the following example , how could i do it ?  <li class="js-stat-show js-stat-show stat-still">
      <a href="#"
          class="request-invoice-popup"
          data-activity-popup-title="invoice 789621 paid"
      >
            
            paid <strong>789621</strong>
      </a>
    </li>

Comment: you could use preg_match("/paid.{0,4}\<strong\>(.*?)\<\/strong\>/i", file_get_contents($myurl), $matches);

Comment: Thanks, Is there any cheat-sheet to learn "RegEx" :) to understand how to make something like "("/paid.{0,4}\<strong\>(.*?)\<\/strong\>/i""

Comment: Yeah look up Regexp on Wikipedia.  If this answer works for you, can you mark as the correct answer?

Comment: if it appears as the following example , how could i do it ? <li class="js-stat-show js-stat-show stat-still"> <a href="#" class="request-invoice-popup" data-activity-popup-title="invoice 78,9621 paid" > paid <strong>78,9621</strong> </a> </li>
and i wanna to use your way but in result it should print" 789621 not 78,9621 " how can i do it ?

Comment: Use the same one, but then use $invoice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $matches[1]);

Comment: Use the above instead of the $invoice = $matches[1]; line

Answer (score 0):

I think you are scraping a webpage, if so, you could use a library like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) With his you can find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.

Then for ex. you could use something like this for getting all the  elements.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('URL');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$input = '<code><div class="show invoice invoice_number_rajhi"><a href="/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people" class="link-blue" onclick="$.fn.colorbox({title:&quot;People who visit this&quot;,onComplete:show.onPeopleOpening,onCleanup:show.onPeopleClosing,href:&‌​quot;/fatora/alrajhi/invoices/3687908533/people&quot;}); return false">789621 paid</a> show this</div></code>';

preg_match_all("#(\d*)[ a-z]*?</a>#i",$input,$out);
echo $out[1][0];
?>
```

You can replace the value of `$input` with `file_get_contents("URL HERE")`;

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the page you can just scrap it with Javascript or jQuery and get the onclick value that you want by targeting the class name.

Answer (score 0):

you would need a [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart) to scrap the invoice from the page. 
then use

```
$ret = $html->find('div[id]');
```

to retrieve the div that contains the invoice.

```
$content=$ret->innertext;
```

gives the content of that div. rest is simple. just split the $content with ' '(space) and get your $invoice